# How to add support for Cosmos db in .Net framework v4.8 Web Api project?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, azure-cosmosdb, .net-4.8

I have a project built in .net framework v4.8 and I have to add support for Cosmos DB to perform CRUD operations. How to achieve that as Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB package is deprecated now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, the Nuget package ***`Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB`*** is deprecated and the Alternate for this is ***`Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos`***

[image]

[image]

Please refer [Generic CRUD Operations For CosmosDB](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/generic-crud-operations-for-cosmosdb/)  for more information

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of public guides about creating applications, including the scenario you are describing: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-api-dotnet-application

If you already have an application using the V2 SDK (Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB), you can use the migration guide to migrate it to V3 (Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos): https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/migrate-dotnet-v3

Comment: No the project is already built without the support for cosmos db and the framework is v4.8 and now have to add its support

Comment: Then you can follow the quickstart's section about Controllers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-api-dotnet-application#declare-and-initialize-services, but there are plenty of examples around, it will depend on how your application is built. And they use the Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos package.